# Sequelize (or clear SQL) query for selecting rows what includes value in JSON field?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

I have rows in my MYSQL and I Need Sequelize.js query.

Every row have col of type JSON what include this for example:

```
[
  {id: 1234, blah: "test"},
  {id: 3210, blah: "test"},
  {id: 5897, blah: "test"}
]
```

I have `id` and I need to select row what include this `id` in at least one object in array.

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#json may be this help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raw mysql query will be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`comments`, '{"id": 1234}');
```

Simple sequelize example:

```
const { fn, col, cast } = this.sequelize;

const User = this.sequelize.define('user', {  
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  comments: DataTypes.JSON,
  defaultValue: [],
})

User.findAll({
  where: fn('JSON_CONTAINS', col('comments'), cast('{"id": 1234}', 'CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8')),
})
.then(users => console.log('result', users.map(u => u.get())))
.catch(err => console.log('error', err));
```

Cast function is used to unescape double quotes around "id" to avoid wrong query string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`comments`, '{\"id\": 1234}');
```

There is one more dirty mysql query example (don't use it):

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `comments` LIKE '%"id": 1234%';
```

Comment: How Can I use OR condition also with JSON_CONTAINS? 

Query is like `SELECT * FROM projects WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`stackholders`, 2) OR owner = 1`